# How to preserve comments when parsing XML with Clojure?

Tags: xml, clojure

I need a way to **preserve comments** when parsing xml from a file.

I've tried `clojure.xml/parse` as well as a couple other really nice libs from github; they all work fine except that every one strips out the comments during parsing.

Can anyone recommend a lib or perhaps a technique with `clojure.xml` that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Did you check this: https://github.com/clojure/data.xml

Comment: oh ok! looks promising.

Comment: so with data.xml, it looks straightforward to emit comments ad-hoc, but i'm not sure if there's a way to preserve them in a round-trip scenario (e.g., slurp in the xml, modify specific elements, then re-emit to filesys)

Comment: Sorry, I never used it, just found it (first hit on Google search btw) and thought it was interesting.

Comment: i appreciate it either way :)

Comment: XML parsing/generation frameworks that preserve comments are rare in *any* language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing some preparsing on the xml string. Seems a bit hacky but it'll do for the moment.

```
(defn preparse-comments
  [s]
  (-> s
    (s/replace #"<!--" "<comment>")
    (s/replace #"-->" "</comment>")))

(defn revert-comments 
  [s]
  (-> s
    (s/replace #"<comment>" "<!--")
    (s/replace #"</comment>" "-->")))

(defn load-data
  [xml-filename]
  (-> xml-filename
    (slurp)
    (preparse-comments)
    (clojure.data.xml/parse-str)))

(defn emit-and-prep
  [data]
  (-> data
    (clojure.data.xml/emit-str)
    (revert-comments)))
```

**Edit:** the above is a pretty barebones approach; if you have tag-bracketing artifacts (e.g., `/>` and so on) in your comments, you'd have to appropriately account for them too somehow so that the preparsing does not render your xml invalid.

Comment: You can mark your question as answered if you're happy with the result.